# Recursive delete in PouchDb/CouchDb?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant, nosql

I am implementing an app using PouchDB sync'd to CouchDB on cloudant. I have a recursive hierarchy of categories.

Clothing

- Tops

  - Shirts

    - T-shirts
    - Dress shirts
  - Jackets

    - Bombers
    - Motorcycle
- Bottoms

  - Pants
  - Shorts

The way I'm storing this is with a "categories" type and each one has a "parentId" - the ones without parents are root nodes. This way, the parent acts as a sort of foreign key I guess.

First off, I don't know if this is the right way to store it but it seems to work just fine in my app. The problem is what do I do when I want to delete?
For instance, If I want to delete "Tops" - I have to go recursively through the tree and execute deletes for each item? is this really the right way to do this? 
seems like with sync, it'll be very "chatty" 
In the case above, I would end up having to fire something like 3 queries and 4 deletes??

Please enlighten me

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have, pretty much, mapped a relational data model into a document store.

Unless there's a good reason not to, I'd recommend having a single "inventory" document with all of the information you're talking about stored in it?  Then the delete you're talking about would be something like:

```
db.get('inventory').then(function(doc) {
  delete doc.tops
  return db.put(doc);
}).then...etc
```

#### Update after comments from OP

Most people do this, they approach document stores with a very *rational-DB* mentality. I'd recommend two different mindset shifts:

1. Think of a document store more like taking the objects that your program has in RAM and just persisting them, as-is, to the disk.
2. Let your *default* be "one single document for all my data" and only make a separate document if there's a reason to.

There may be other reasons to create more than one document, but for me the two primary reasons are:

1. Uniqueness: the `_id` of a document is the only thing within CouchDB that will give you that system-wide (or DB-wide really) mechanism/check/constraint. So things like users, with unique usernames, I put in their own documents.
2. Avoiding conflicts: if you have multiple clients updating the same data, eg. customer orders coming into your system, **especially** with multiple nodes all replicating back with each other. Splitting things up so that concurrent writes are not happening on the same document will make your life much easier.

Other than for those reasons I would recommend leaving everything in a single document, and then creating meaningful views so you can get just the data you want.

So to your specific followup questions:

> are you saying to have 1 doc to host the full tree?

Yes, as I said above, *I recommend having a single "inventory" document*.

> is that a common way to store this type of data?

I don't know how common/uncommon, I know a lot of people make the mistake you were making and approach document stores with a relational mentality, so that's probably quite common. It's not a good approach though and leads to many headaches because document stores do not have the same features as RDBMSs, eg. lack of transactions for multiple document updates.

> are there any downsides to this approach?

Other than the uniqueness and conflict things I mentioned above, no.

> if I have "shirt 1", i want it to belong to tops/shirts/t-shirts so some sort of ID is necessary

Think about how you'd do this in RAM.

Eg. rather than the structure you were thinking, you might have this document structure instead:

```
{
  "_id": "inventory",
  "skus": {
    "123456": {
      "sku": "123456",
      "name": "Purple T-Shirt",
      "tags": [ "top", "t-shirt", "shirt", "purple" ]
    },

    # ...
}
```

And then **in a view** you will produce a lookup for your data by tag, eg:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc._id == "inventory") {
    for(var sku in doc.skus) {
      var item = doc.skus[sku]
      item.tags.forEach( function(tag) { emit( tag, sku ) })
    }
  }
}
```

So then you can use that view to look up any sku you want, and then you would use: `doc.items[sku]` to retrieve it. Or you could put that item in your `emit` output if you were happy to have that data in your index.

Comment: are you saying to have 1 doc to host the full tree? I thought of that initially but it somehow seemed "wrong" - is that a common way to store this type of data? are there any downsides to this approach?

Comment: subsequently, I need to store references to particular tree nodes. for instance, if I have "shirt 1", i want it to belong to tops/shirts/t-shirts so some sort of ID is necessary

Comment: Thanks for the update - you say that you use different docs for different users - isnt that an inherent security issue? can't any user just query for "all"? or are you using an intermediate proxy-like setup that limits what a certain user can access? Also, if you're storing the whole "inventory" in one object, i would imagine a downside might be the size of the data being shuffled back and forth - you're updating your whole data store every time there's any update, right? For mobile apps, this may be an issue unless it's just a timed sync that happens occasionally.

Comment: Yeah, there's an app/proxy that stands between my DB and my users. No user can query the CouchDB directly. Re the size of data being shuffled back and forth, yes, and if I had a lot of updates to very specific parts of the data structure then I'd consider splitting it up into multiple documents.